# Animate individual routes with react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router and I want to be able to render and transition arbitrary components when mounting and unmounting. Right now I have added the components to my route definition:

```
<Route component={App}>
    <Route
      path="foo"
      component={Foo}
    />
    <Route
      path="bar"
      component={Bar}
    />
</Route>
```

I use react css transition group in my components to animate them when they enter and leave. The components mount and animate propery when they are entering. But when I leave the route, the rendered component is immediately removed and there is thus no leave animation.

The typical solution is to add the transition group to the parent so that it isnt unmounted, and from there animate the children. This doesn't work for me because `Foo` component and `Bar` component use completely different animations.

In short I believe I need a way to individually animate routes and not the typical "transition between routes". For example, navigating between `/` and `/foo` should yield the following:

1. Be on `/`, navigate to `/foo` -> the `Foo` component animates in.
2. Be on `/foo`, navigate to anywhere else, like `/` -> the `Foo` component animates out.

I hope this makes sense, thanks!

Comment: I have added some example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe, you can delay transition, in order to allow to complete "leave" animation

**1) with onChange** jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/qnpj0odc/7/

```
const func = ({location:{pathname:prev}}, nextState, replace, callback)=>{
    prev=="/foo" ? setTimeout(callback,3000)
    :prev=="/bar" ? setTimeout(callback,2000)
    :callback();
};

<Route  path="/" component={App} onChange={func}>
    <Route path="foo" component={Foo} />
    <Route path="bar" component={Bar} />
</Route>
```

[image]

---

**2) with setRouteLeaveHook** https://jsfiddle.net/qnpj0odc/24/

```
class Foo extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={leave:0};
    props.router.setRouteLeaveHook(props.route,n=>this.startAnim(n))
  }
  startAnim(next){
    this.setState({leave:1});
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.allow=1;
      this.props.router.push(next.pathname);},500)
    return !!this.allow;
  }
  render(){
    return (
        <h1 className={"animated zoomIn"+(this.state.leave?" zoomOut ":"")}>FOO</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

**3) with listenBefore** https://jsfiddle.net/qnpj0odc/23/

```
class Foo extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.state={leave:0};
     this.cb = props.router.listenBefore((loc,cb)=>{
       loc.pathname == props.location.pathname ?
       this.setState({leave:0}) :
       this.setState({leave:1},()=>setTimeout(cb,500))});
  }
  componentWillUnmount(){
    this.cb(); //unlisten
  }
  render(){
    return (
        <h1 className={"animated zoomIn"+(this.state.leave?" zoomOut ":"")}>FOO</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. This seems like an alright solution, but means I have to stick extra animation login into my routing table which does not seem ideal and might quickly get out of hand. Double maintenance problems etc.

Comment: I have added example without onChange  in  routing table